# SOAP12 missing soap action - spring

Tags: java, spring, soap

I am trying to make a simple SOAP request but I am getting this error:

```
org.springframework.ws.soap.client.SoapFaultClientException: Unable to handle request without a valid action parameter. Please supply a valid soap action.
```

I am using `soap12`. Here is my code:

```
MessageFactory msgFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance(SOAPConstants.SOAP_1_2_PROTOCOL);
SaajSoapMessageFactory saajSoapMessageFactory = new SaajSoapMessageFactory(msgFactory);
WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate = new WebServiceTemplate(saajSoapMessageFactory);

Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
marshaller.setPackagesToScan("packageName");
marshaller.afterPropertiesSet();

webServiceTemplate.setMarshaller(marshaller);
webServiceTemplate.afterPropertiesSet();

Object response = webServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive("https://www.w3schools.com/xml/tempconvert.asmx", temperature);
```

I tried setting `Content-Type` with `WebServiceMessageCallback` to text/xml but it didn't get overriden.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution by adding:

```
MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance(SOAPConstants.SOAP_1_2_PROTOCOL);
SaajSoapMessageFactory saajSoapMessageFactory = new SaajSoapMessageFactory(messageFactory);
saajSoapMessageFactory.setSoapVersion(SoapVersion.SOAP_12);
saajSoapMessageFactory.afterPropertiesSet();
```